# Nginx+PHP scalability on Windows

Tags: windows, php, web-server, scalability

I'm trying to understand Nginx+PHP scalability running Windows with, lets say, 100 requests  doing a medium-term operations.

Analyzing source code I saw:

1. Nginx start a spawns itself several times depending on
   configuration and/or server processors count.
2. Altough it uses I/O completion ports, each worker only creates
   one thread to handle requests.
3. When a PHP request is done, Nginx communicates with PHP using FastCGI

At this point, although NGinx can continue scaling, I cannot see in standard PHP fastcgi sapi code that scales using multiple threads/processes and completion ports.

For unix/linux, PHP-FPM come to solve the problem because it forks child processes to complete tasks altough not sure about the performance.

But back into Windows, still in PHP-FPM, I don't see specific code to mantain the whole webserver performance high.

Is there an alternative for Windows? Is something wrong in my research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scalability of nginx on Windows is limited, so it's not a recommended platform for a production web site.

[From the nginx web site](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html):

> Version of nginx for Windows uses the native Win32 API (not the Cygwin emulation layer). Only the `select()` connection processing method is currently used, so high performance and scalability should not be expected.
>
> Although several workers can be started, only one of them actually does any work.
>
> A worker can handle no more than 1024 simultaneous connections.

Comment: Here is a non-offical Nginx build optimized for Windows, with multi-worker support and lots of modules added. http://nginx-win.ecsds.eu/

Comment: Thanks so much for this link. I had no it existed.  I wish I had known sooner.